# Error in m1 * m2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator (mantel test)

Tags: r, r-ape

I'm trying to do Mantel test with symmetric matrices

```
mat1 chr [1:30] "Ind1" "Ind2" "Ind3" "Ind4" "Ind5"
mat2 chr [1:30] "Ind1" "Ind2" "Ind3" "Ind4" "Ind5"
```

I have 5 individuals in both matrices with symmetric frequency data, and ran like below.

```
mat1<-read.csv("GroupSinfantprox1.csv",sep=",", header=T, skip=0)
mat2<-read.csv("GroupSjuvenileprox1.csv",sep=",", header=T, skip=0)

mat1<-as.matrix(mat1)
mat2<-as.matrix(mat2)

mantel.test(mat1, mat2, nperm=999, graph=FALSE, alternative="two.sided")
```

However, I got an error message

> Error in m1 * m2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I don't know how to deal with this error to do Mantel test.

Comment: What package are you using? I see `mantel.test` functions in several packages: `lazyWeave`, `ape`, `ncf`, `cultevo`... The `ape` package documentation specifically says the inputs should be numeric matrices, but yours are character matrices.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for your comment. I used ape package. Maybe I can try others, but what if I want to stick to package ape? Converting character to numeric matrices is fine? I already tried it and failed.

Comment: I've never used the `ape` package before and I don't know what a `mantel.test` is nor what your data represent. I just glanced at the help page.

Comment: @GregorThomas Okay. Thank you for information. I will try more on other packages or find out the solution. Thanks!